# Import python module from external url

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-module

I am building a **Python script** for processing json data according to some criteria.
Also I have built a **custom module** which consists of **methods for retrieving json data and generation of json file which consist of processed data.**
But that **module file is stored into S3 bucket** and **I need to import that module into my script** so that I can invoke functions defined in module.

Please suggest me appropriate solution regarding importing **python** module from external URL

Comment: Why is the module on S3? Why not install it in your project?

Comment: or cleanly package it so you can deploy it with pip...

Answer (score 0):

[Package](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/) your module into your favorite extension (tarball, wheel, etc.) using setuptools and then you will be able to install it using pip as bruno by doing something like:

```
pip install --no-index --trusted-host s3_ip/host --find-links http://s3.com...
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could download the file using urllib2 and then import it, if the online module is all in one file:

```py
from urllib2 import urlopen
r = urlopen('http://urlHere/fileHere')  
f = open('filenameToWrite', 'w')
f.write(r.read())
f.close()
import filenameWithout.PyInIt
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see my answer to [question # 48905127](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48905127/importing-py-files-in-google-colab/57402465#57402465) - believed to be the best solution I found so far and comes with **detailed steps** and **code snippets** ready for you to copy and use.