# Importing .py files in Google Colab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, ipython, google-colaboratory

Is there any way to upload my code in .py files and import them in colab code cells?

The other way I found is to create a local Jupyter notebook then upload it to Colab, is it the only way?

Answer (score 164, accepted):

You can save it first, then import it.

```
from google.colab import files
src = list(files.upload().values())[0]
open('mylib.py','wb').write(src)
import mylib
```

Update (nov 2018): Now you can upload easily by

- click at [>] to open the left pane
- choose file tab
- click [upload] and choose your [mylib.py]
- import mylib

Update (oct 2019): If you don't want to upload every time, you can store it in S3 and mount it to Colab, as shown in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/korakot/e28ea5269129b70f220fe5e8d065b446)

Update (apr 2020): Now that you can mount your Google Drive automatically. It is easier to just copy it from Drive than upload it.

- Store `mylib.py` in your Drive
- Open a new Colab
- Open the (left)side pane, select `Files` view
- Click `Mount Drive` then `Connect to Google Drive`
- Copy it by `!cp drive/MyDrive/mylib.py .`
- `import mylib`

Comment: @rsam Then try the second method. I tried it and it worked for me.

Comment: files.upload() currently does not work in Firefox. Alternative way is to upload it into Google Drive, then from a notebook use PyDrive to download it.

Comment: If you use the file tab method you have to repeat the upload each runtime

Comment: I now add the method to store it in S3, so you don't need to upload again.

Comment: I am facing the error given below, please let me know anyone of you have any idea 
"cp: missing destination file operand after '/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/attention.py'"

Comment: @eswaraamirthans You forget the dot "." at the end.

Comment: where can I insert the command !cp "drive/My Drive/mylib.py" . ?

Comment: @WesinAlves: You can add it into a code cell and execute it the same way as you would execute python code. You also might to have to remove the space in 'My Drive' -> 'MyDrive'.

Comment: Thank you for this tutorial. How about opening a .py from Github repo in colab?

Comment: Now you need to add "/content" after the path, so it would be !cp drive/MyDrive/mylib.py /content

Comment: It took me a while to find that I forgot to add the `.` at end of `!cp drive/MyDrive/mylib.py .`. Anyhow, this is a clean and nice solution. Solved my big problem. Thanks a ton. Moreover, I really appreciate for updating the answer with colab updating time to time. Really appreciate that.

Answer (score 123):

In case anyone else is interested to know how to import files/packages from gdrive inside a google colab. The following procedure worked for me:

**1) Mount your google drive in google colab:**

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive/')
```

**2) Append the directory to your python path using sys:**

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/content/gdrive/mypythondirectory')
```

Now you should be able to import stuff from that directory!

Comment: Hello. Thank you. But I am looking for importing python files that depend on other files as well. Can I do that please?

Comment: from google.colab import drive 
import sys

drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
colab_notebooks_path = "gdrive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/"

sys.path.append(colab_notebooks_path)

Answer (score 20):

1. You can upload local files to google colab by using *upload()* function in *google.colab.files*
2. If you have files on github, then clone the repo using 
   !git clone https://github.com/username/repo_name.git. Then just like in jupyter notebook load it using the magic function *%load* `%load filename.py`.

Comment: The second method worked for me, I just had to add the name of the repo: `%load repo_name/filename.py`

Comment: @xyzjayne did you try importing it? I can load it fine, but can't use it as a module

Answer (score 15):

Based on the answer by Korakot Chaovavanich, I created the function below to download all files needed within a Colab instance.

```
from google.colab import files
def getLocalFiles():
    _files = files.upload()
    if len(_files) >0:
       for k,v in _files.items():
         open(k,'wb').write(v)
getLocalFiles()
```

You can then use the usual 'import' statement to import your local files in Colab. I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, I am a noobie and this is the only answer I understood how to implement and it works for me

Answer (score 7):

We can do so.

```
import sys
import os

py_file_location = "/content/drive/My Drive"
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(py_file_location))
```

Now you can import it as module in notebook for that location.

```
import whatever
```

Comment: `/content` doesn't contain `drive`. So it is impossible to access my files

Answer (score 4):

I face the same problem. After reading numerous posts, I would like to introduce the following solution I finally chose over many other methods (e.g. use `urllib`, `httpimport`, clone from GitHub, package the modules for installation, etc). The solution utilizes **Google Drive API** ([official doc](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/PyDrive)) for proper authorization.

#### Advantages:

1. Easy and safe (no need for code to handle file operation exceptions and/or additional authorization)
2. Module files safeguarded by Google account credentials (no one else can view/take/edit them)
3. You control what to upload/access (you can change/revoke access anytime on a file-by-file basis)
4. Everything in one place (no need to rely upon or manage another file hosting service)
5. Freedom to rename/relocate module files (not path-based and won't break your/other's notebook code)

#### Steps:

1. Save your .py module file to Google Drive - you should have that since you're already using Colab
2. Right click on it, "Get shareable link", copy the part after "`id=`" - the file id assigned by Google Drive
3. Add and run the following code snippets to your Colab notebook:

```py
!pip install pydrive                             # Package to use Google Drive API - not installed in Colab VM by default
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
```

```py
from google.colab import auth                    # Other necessary packages
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
```

```py
auth.authenticate_user()                         # Follow prompt in the authorization process
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
```

```py
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)
your_module = drive.CreateFile({"id": "your_module_file_id"})   # "your_module_file_id" is the part after "id=" in the shareable link
your_module.GetContentFile("your_module_file_name.py")          # Save the .py module file to Colab VM
import your_module_file_name                                    # Ready to import. Don't include".py" part, of course :)
```

#### Side note

Last but not least, I should credit the [original contributor](https://www.pingshiuanchua.com/blog/post/importing-your-own-python-module-or-python-file-in-colaboratory) of this approach. That post might have some typo in the code as it triggered an error when I tried it. After more reading and troubleshooting my code snippets above worked (as of today on Colab VM OS: Linux 4.14.79).

Comment: Umm  when i try to call a function in the imported py file this code gives me error

Answer (score 3):

Try this way:

I have a package named plant_seedlings. The package is stored in google drive. What I should do is to copy this package in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/.

```
!cp /content/drive/ai/plant_seedlings.tar.gz /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/

!cd /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ && tar -xzf plant_seedlings.tar.gz

!cd /content

!python -m plant_seedlings
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. "/content" does not have "drive" subdirectory.

Comment: I am not sure of this answer but for your problem, you should first click `Mount Drive` button of google drive. Then drive folder will appear under content folder.

Answer (score 2):

Below are the steps that worked for me

1. #### Mount your google drive in google colab

   from google.colab import drive
   drive.mount('/content/drive')
2. #### Insert the directory

   import sys
   sys.path.insert(0,’/content/drive/My Drive/ColabNotebooks’)
3. #### check the current directory path

   %cd drive/MyDrive/ColabNotebooks
   %pwd
4. #### Import your module or file

   import my_module
5. If you get the following error 'Name Null is not defined' then do the following

   5.1 Download my_module.ipynb from colab as my_module.py file (file->Download .py)

   5.2 Upload the *.py file to drive/MyDrive/ColabNotebooks in Google drive

   5.3 import my_module will work now

Reference:
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/importing-your-own-python-module-or-python-file-into-colab-3e365f0a35ec

https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/1358

Answer (score 2):

Here's my process:

```
import sys 
sys.path.insert(0, '/content/drive/MyDrive/my_folder')
%cd /content/drive/MyDrive/my_folder
%pwd
```

Now, you can import the module from that path using `import my_module` easily

Answer (score 2):

This is how I regularly do it:

1. Save my module in the directory. Say MyFile.py in MyModules
2. Define the location of my module:

   `path_m = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/MyModules/'`
3. Then I add the path to sys.path:

   ```
   import sys

   sys.path.insert(0,path_m)
   ```
4. `import the module into my Jupyter/Google Colab notebook.`

   `import MyFile`

Answer (score 1):

You can upload those .py files to Google drive and allow Colab to use to them:

```
!mkdir -p drive
!google-drive-ocamlfuse drive
```

All your files and folders in root folder will be in `drive`.

Comment: you first have to install the FUSE filesystem for google drive before you can do that

Comment: Actually mine works with only those lines above. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

It's Jun 2019.
Make sure in the Python package's `__init__.py` all related files are imported in order. Push the code to Git or use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50291330/618018).

for e.g,

```
from .Boxes import *
from .Circles import *
from .Rectangles import *
...
```

Don't use Package name in `__init__.py` file for importing the files.

in Google colab,

```
! rm -rf SorghumHeadDetection
! git clone https://github.com/user/amazing-repo-name/
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by mount your drive to colab and write some code to put the id of your python file
you can find code here
[importing python file from drive to colab](https://github.com/basmahajjaj/Importing_pythonFiles_fromdrive_tocolab)

```
    # Code to read file into colaboratory:
     !pip install -U -q PyDrive
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials


#Autheticate E-Mail ID
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

#2.1 Get the file
your_module = drive.CreateFile({"id": 'write your file id here'})  # "your_module_file_id" is the part after "id=" in the shareable link
your_module.GetContentFile("write the file name here")          # Save the .py module file to Colab VM

import file_name   
from file_name import anything    #as classes or functions from your file
```

Answer (score 0):

`os.listdir` can be used to view all files in the directory

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount("/content/drive")

import os
path="/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks"
os.chdir(path)
os.listdir(path)`
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the file I was trying to use was called `client.py`. This raised a conflict because there's already a library called `client` in `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/`.

I solved this by uploading the `client.py` file to the same Google Drive folder in which the Colab Notebook is saved in and change its name to something unique that doesn't appear in the `dist-packages` folder.

In my case, I changed the file name to `dfsclient.py` and then just imported it with

`import dfsclient`

Then I implemented Kamal's answer:

```
import sys 
sys.path.insert(0, '/content/drive/MyDrive/my_folder')
```

Answer (score -3):

A easy way is

1. type in
   from google.colab import files
   uploaded = files.upload()
2. copy the code
3. paste in colab cell