# How to import python files in google colaboratory?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I am trying to run my program on Google Colab; where my code make use of .py files written seprately.

In normal system I have all files inside one folder and it works using `import xyz`, but when I tried using same folder in Google drive it gives import error.

Answer (score 13):

Now in googlecolab(Nov 18) you can upload your python files easily

- Navigate to Files (Tab on your left panel)
- Click on UPLOAD Upload your python folder or .py files
- Use googlecolab book to access the file.

Please check my screenshot below! 
[image]

Answer (score 7):

If you have just 2-3 files, you can try the solution I gave in another question here.

[Importing .py files in Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48905127/importing-py-files-in-google-colab/48919022#48919022)

But if you have something like 5-10 files, I would suggest you put your library on github, then `!git clone` it to Google Colab. Another solution is to zip all you library files, then modify the first solution by unzipping with `!unzip mylib.zip`

If those library files are not in a folder structure, just a few files in the same folder. You can upload and save them then import them. Upload them with:

```
def upload_files():
  from google.colab import files
  uploaded = files.upload()
  for k, v in uploaded.items():
    open(k, 'wb').write(v)
  return list(uploaded.keys())
```

Comment: Which methods have you tried? What’s the error message? Try harder. 

Answer (score 0):

For example you have a module like this

```
simple.py
def helloworld():
   print("hello")
```

Click arrow on left panel => Choose File tab => Upload simple.py
In notebook code like this

```
import simple
simple.helloworld()
=> hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Something I've used when I have multiple python scripts and want to automatically import through code is to set it up as a package and clone from the repo.

First set up the scripts in a repo with a `setup.py` and `__init__.py` files (obviously).

Then add this to the top of your notebook:

```
!rm -rf <repo-name>  # in case you need to refresh after pushing changes 
!git clone https://github.com/<user>/<repo-name>.git
```

Then install the package:

```
!pip install ./<repo-name>
```

Now conveniently import functions or whatever:

```
from <app-name>.<module> import <function>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this easiest way

```
    from google.colab import drive
    drive.mount('/content/drive')
    %cd /content/drive/MyDrive/directory-location
```