# In Google Colab Python Notebook, what's the cleanest way to import other .py files?

Tags: python, import, python-import

I am trying to avoid using sys.path.append...or any hacks and want to organise the folders. Given I have a notebook .ipynb file, how can I import .py files if I place them in a directory ?

Answer (score 0):

If you place them in the same directory, you can import your module (`.py`) files easily with:

```
from my_module import * # This will import all functions
from my_module import foo # This will import only my_module.foo

foo()
```

or simply import the module

```
import my_module

my_module.foo()
```

Refer to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) python documentation for more explanation about module.

**Update on updated question**

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53982547) answer, you can use the above approach if you upload your module. Just ensure your `pwd` is correct.

Better yet in the sample, you can define `__init__.py` inside your module folder (refer to section *6.4. Packages* in the doc above) to do something like:

```
from folder.my_module import foo

foo()
```

Comment: Not when you run from Colaboratory http://colab.research.google.com  , the above won't work. You can append the path and that works but there must be a cleaner way.

Comment: @KamaliOS you should’ve mention this is specific to google colab in your question. Your current question is about python notebook in general.

Comment: My mistake. Updated. Thanks.