# Using colab for python ADT's

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-colaboratory, abstract-data-type

I am trying to use colab to import a python file and use the files function. For example, my first file has the function:

```
def test():
  return 'foo'
```

and when I try to call it in my other file like this:

```
import test_adt as t

t.test()
```

I get the error `AttributeError: module 'test_adt' has no attribute 'test'`

Is there something I'm missing here or is colab currently not capable of doing this?

**Edit:** it's in the correct directory, when you `print(t)` it returns:

```
<module 'test_adt' from '/content/test_adt.py'>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your example. I ran into the exact same problem, but when I clicked "**Restart Runtime**", and tried again, it worked. I think you just need to restart the runtime in order to clear the import cache after editing the .py file. (Once it works, you can see the problem more clearly by editing and saving the .py file — changes don't take effect in the notebook until you restart the runtime again.)

FYI here are some related questions, although beware of outdated answers.

- [Importing .py files in Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48905127/importing-py-files-in-google-colab/50291330)
- [How to import python files in google colaboratory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49151168/how-to-import-python-files-in-google-colaboratory?rq=1)

Comment: still not working for me. I ended up just using visual studio for now, hopefully I can get this figured out soon. Thanks for your reply