# Problems importing custom library in google colab

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, google-colaboratory

I am doing some machine learning project and want to run the project on google colab since my own machine is too weak for it and hangs when i try to run the project on it. My project has the structure as shown in picture .
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47JbT.png).
I have multiple .py files each importing modules from one another. I converted the project to .zip file in my pc and then used the upload tab on google colab to upload the project. i unzipped the file and tried to run one code from the "examples" folder which is importing some function from the modAL function like this

```
from modAL.models import ActiveLearner.
```

this import is failing on google colab with error " no module named modAL " . Can someone please tell me how to get around this issue? The code works just fine on my own laptop.

Comment: Potential duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52733786/how-to-import-custom-modules-in-google-colab)

Answer (score 1):

I found this explanation: https://zerowithdot.com/colab-workspace/  - very useful.
After creating a space in your google drive

```
from os.path import join
from google.colab import drive
ROOT = "/content/drive"
drive.mount(ROOT)
```

fetch the git repo

```
GIT_USERNAME = "xxx"
GIT_TOKEN = "xxx"
GIT_REPOSITORY = "Repo"

!mkdir "{PROJECT_PATH}"
!git clone https://{GIT_TOKEN}@github.com/{GIT_USERNAME}/{GIT_REPOSITORY}.git " 
{PROJECT_PATH}"
```

Finally use importlib to get access to definitions

```
from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader
somemodule = SourceFileLoader('somelib', join(PROJECT_PATH, 
'utils/somelib.py')).load_module()
```

Answer (score 0):

If the project is public (probably possible to make it work otherwise too) you can create a package [1] and install it with pip:

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/myuser/myproject
```

[1] https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/