# How to import custom modules in google colab? (Solution given here not working)

Tags: python-import, importerror, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to import a custom module called 'clusterer.py' into my colab notebook. But the import function is not able to find the file. Is there any other way to import custom modules?

After mounting the drive, I have already tried this approach: [How to import custom modules in google colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52733786/how-to-import-custom-modules-in-google-colab) with the result: 'No module named 'clusterer''

```
!ls /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/Colab\ Notebooks/Omdena_Mars_Anomaly_Detection/*.py
!cat /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/Colab\ Notebooks/Omdena_Mars_Anomaly_Detection/clusterer.py
import sys
sys.path.append('/content/gdrive/My\ Drive/Colab\ Notebooks/Omdena_Mars_Anomaly_Detection')
import clusterer
```

The output is as follows:
'/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Omdena_Mars_Anomaly_Detection/clusterer.py'

'/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Omdena_Mars_Anomaly_Detection/feature_extractor.py'

[Contents of the module 'clusterer.py']

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clusterer'

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think I figured out one solution. In my case, I had to physically go inside the directory where the files were. This is what I did

1a. Restart the kernel but 'resetting all runtimes', specially if you've just added your file.py to the directory.

1b.`cd gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Omdena_Mars_Anomaly_Detection`

2. `!ls /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/Colab\Notebooks/Omdena_Mars_Anomaly_Detection/*.py`
3. `!cat /content/gdrive/My\ Drive/Colab\ Notebooks/Omdena_Mars_Anomaly_Detection/mylib.py`
4. `import sys
   sys.path.append('/content/gdrive/My\ Drive/Colab\ Notebooks/Omdena_Mars_Anomaly_Detection')`

   5.`import clusterer`

Worked for me. 
Thanks