# Why module cannot be found in google colab?

Tags: python, module, python-import, google-colaboratory

I want to import a module in google colab.

I did follow the instructions written here: 
[How to import custom modules in google colab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52733786/how-to-import-custom-modules-in-google-colab)

Nevertheless, I get a message that this module does not exist having followed these steps. 
I can list the file in the working directory using the ls command. Even specifying the path, where to look for the module did not help.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/calculator.py')
```

Calling `import calculator`evaluates to a ModuleNotFoundError.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that I have found the solution. 
It all comes down to the working directory, which has not been correctly set :(

```
from google.colab import drive 
drive.mount('/content/drive')
%cd /content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks
```

Then you can write a file, for example:

```
%%writefile calc.py
PI = 3.14

def add(a,b):
  return (a + b)
print (add(2,3))

def area(radius):
  return PI * radius * radius

print(area(5))
```

And lastly, it can be imported:

```
import ctes3t
```

Answer (score 4):

You should not set module name in sys.path.append call, only directory containing custom modules:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/content/gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks')

import calculator
```

Comment: Hi Aleksey, sure thing. I think that I have found my mistake, as my working directory was not the same, where the file was stored.