# How do I create modules in Google Colab so that I can import and use them in other files?

Tags: python, oop, module, google-colaboratory

I could not upload .py files in Google Colab at the first place and also I am not sure how to import modules created within Google Colab or system environment?

I thought of creating and importing modules in system but could not do it due to issues in PTVS. Couldn't figure out what the issue is.

I need to create number of modules which can retrieve data, preprocess the same, run query, retrieve results and rank them. I am not very comfortable with Python's module syntax. Is there any way I can learn them in an intuitive way as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing .py files in Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48905127/importing-py-files-in-google-colab)