# Python modules in google colaboratory not seeing their imports

Tags: python, import, module, google-colaboratory

I am trying to download my python library to Google Colaboratory environment and make it work. The structure of the library is:

- lib

  - **init**.py
  - module

    - **init**.py
    - file1
    - file2

In `file1` I import `file2` with

```
from file2 import *
```

Then I am trying to use my library in the notebook with

```
from lib.module import file1
```

and I am getting this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'file2'.

Importing `file2` works fine. The problem is with the `file1`, which imports `file2`.

I tried to use the package locally and everything worked fine.

In both cases lib was in the working directory.

Could you explain the difference between using the package in Google Colaboratory and locally?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing .py files in Google Colab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48905127/importing-py-files-in-google-colab)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I have clarified what my problem is.  The issue is only with importing files that have relative imports in them.