# How to import python classes or modules in to google Colab?

Tags: python, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, google-colaboratory

I'm mounting google drive in Colab.I'm able to load csv files from drive after mounting.
I need import python classes.
In the following structure,
How can i import fileA, fileB and fileC in Colab?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48905127/importing-py-files-in-google-colab/48919022

Comment: It got solved, I was running from default root folder, understood by using %ls command, routed to the directory where files are kept using %cd cmd and its working from there.