# Just using the GPU from Colab Pro

Tags: python, machine-learning, gpu, google-colaboratory

I am working on a research projet this summer. That project is to extend some functionalities of a machine learning program (Located on github). I can't really train the models on my laptop as I just have 16 gigs of ram (CPU). This project is dispatched over several python files and directories. Is it possible to use Colab Pro to run this program without rewriting the python code in the Colab cells? I just need the GPU.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

1. Upload your Python files to Google Drive
2. Mount Google Drive to Colab
3. Copy Python files from Google Drive to Colab working directory
4. Import your Python modules/packages in Colab

You can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48919022/9802625) for more details.