# How to import python files in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

So I have been trying to make this file compatible to Google Colab but I'm not able to find any way to do it.

[[image: Files Arrangement]]

EfficientDet-DeepSORT-Tracker is the main folder of this entire package

[image]

This picture is from one of the files placed alongside backbone.py

How to fix the fact that the file isn't able to detect backbone.py?

EDIT for more context: I shared the errors I found when trying to run waymo_open_dataset.py which isn't able to detect the other .py files alongside it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this past question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48905127/importing-py-files-in-google-colab) you could import 'filename' of the filename.py. So in the main.py file you are trying to run in colab, then import the required files in the main.py file.

Comment: Didn't work. It is still not able to find the files. Also, that past question has nothing to do with what I've asked. I have these files in Google Colab already and I'm trying to import properties of 1 python file into another.